# In react why do I have to click twice on this radio?

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, input, radio-button

This radio button does not display as checked. When I click on it it becomes checked. If you remove the name property it works fine.

this is in a functional stateless (dumb) component.

```
const dumbComp = ()=>(<input type="radio" name="asdf" checked="true" /> <h1>YO!</h1>)
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how the presence or lack of 'name' affects the behavior here.

A few others have replicated this (within our codebase).

help me, my mind is melting over here...

### Edit

BUT I cannot replicate this in a jsbin/pen/etc. This makes me suspect that the issue is somewhere higher in the stack.

This makes the question more one of...

Is there a stack that will replicate the bug with this component?

Comment: so.... where's the react?

Comment: Your post seems incomplete. This pen may help you understand where is your problem:https://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/mAxPvj

Comment: EXACTLY! This is soooo simple... why does it matter?
const dumbComp = ()=>(<input type="radio" name="asdf" checked="true" /> <h1>YO!</h1>);
if that helps

Comment: You need to change checked="true". This needs to be controlled dynamically via state.

Comment: Well.. What you showed now almost works (You should put the checked value in curly braces, like checked={true}), see: https://codesandbox.io/s/7zz3pklvkj
So I guess the problem is rather in the context?

Comment: @Hamed "needs"? i mean, it only needs to be controlled by the state if the state needs to control it. "true" should still at the very least default it to selected.

Comment: @KevinB You are correct, my bad. I mean if it needs to be controlled by the state, it shouldn't be hardcoded.

Comment: The issue must be somewhere in the context around it. I've spent quite a while trying to reproduce the error in the plunk/pen/etc and haven't been able to. I still don't know why that issue would crop up at the level it does, but I'll edit this since it clearly lacks the information to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, just let the state set the checked value of your input.

Example:

```
<input type="radio" onChange={() => onCheck()} name="asdf" checked={this.state.checked} /> <h1>YO!</h1>
```

when:

```
onCheck() => {
  //This reverts the value of checked key
  this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked});
}
```